# LINQ Design Curiosity: Skip/Take vs. SkipWhile/TakeWhile

Tags: c#, linq

Is there any particular reason to have separate methods `Skip` and `SkipWhile`, rather than simply having overloads of the same method?

What I mean is, instead of `Skip(int)`, `SkipWhile(Func<TSource,bool>)`, and `SkipWhile(Func<TSource,int,bool>)`, why not have `Skip(int)`, `Skip(Func<TSource,bool>)`, and `Skip(Func<TSource,int,bool>)`? I'm sure there's *some* reason for it, as the whole LINQ system was designed by people with much more experience than me, but that reasoning is not apparent.

The only possibility that's come to mind has been issues with the parser for the SQL-like syntax, but that already distinguishes between things like `Select(Func<TSource,TResult>)` and `Select(Func<TSource,int,TResult>)`, so I doubt that's why.

The same question applies to `Take` and `TakeWhile`, which are complimentary to the above.

Edit: To clarify, I *am aware* of the functional differences between the variants, I'm merely asking about the design decision on the naming of the methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMO, the only reason would be **better readability**. `Skip` sound like “Skip N number of records”, while `SkipWhile` sounds like “Skip until a condition is met”. These names are **self-explanatory**

Comment: Sometimes you don't know how many items to skip. Depending on the data model, working out how many items to skip and then skipping mat be more expensive than just skipping by condition.

Comment: @Gusdor, if the number is known then `Skip` should be used, if it based on condition `SkipWhile` should be used, I think the question is why not have two overloads for `Skip` and `SkipWhile`

Comment: Well, the question is "why have `SkipWhile` at all, when it could simply be folded into `Skip` overloads?" Readability and self-explanatory names are certainly good reasons for the difference; such things are best practices in other bits of code (C# or otherwise), so why not Microsoft's standard libraries! =)

Answer (score 2):

The "While" indicates that LINQ will only skip *while the lambda expression evaluates to true,* and will stop skipping as soon as it is no longer true. This is a very different thing from just skipping a fixed number of items.

The same reasoning holds true for Take, of course.

All is well in the interest of clarity!